# how to apply a condition to a queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to programming, I have a doubt I formed the QuerySet with table data i want to know how to apply condition to the formed queryset and get the count.

Code :

```
final_set = TaskMaster.objects.filter(istaskactive=True)
```

I want something like

```
no_of_rebuild_task = final_set..objects.filter(tasktype.id=1).count
```

model.py

```
class TaskMaster(models.Model):
  sid = models.CharField(max_length=3)
  # Remember to change the default value in processor in production
  processor = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
  tasktype = models.ForeignKey(TaskTypeTable, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  task_title = models.TextField(null=True)
  task_description = models.TextField(null=True)
  datacenter = models.ForeignKey(DatacenterTable,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  priority = models.ForeignKey(PriorityTable, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  status = models.ForeignKey(StatusTable, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  pid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
  sourceincident = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
  errorincident = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
  processingteam = 
  models.ForeignKey(TeamTable,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  createddate = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
  duedate = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
  istaskactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django ORM you can use `count()` to count the number of records in the selected table.
So for your query it can be

```
no_of_rebuild_task = TaskMaster.objects.filter(istaskactive=True, tasktype_id=1).count()
```

See effective way of [Django ORM](http://www.effectivedjango.com/orm.html)
and [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) here.

Answer (score 0):

```
no_of_rebuild_task = final_set.filter(tasktype__id=1).count()
```